# rpm spec file %pre and script files

Tags: rpm, pre, specifications

I would like to get some help regarding spec file and specifically the `%pre` section.

What I would like to do is, in the %pre section I want to be able to refer and use to a .sh file.

I got this idea from the following link
[rpmbuild: using script files contained in the package in %pre script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813436/rpmbuild-using-script-files-contained-in-the-package-in-pre-script)

In the link above keep the focus on the fact that in the preamble section of the spec file, a source .sh file is declared.

Source0:xyz.sh
....
....

The `%pre` section then uses  the xyz.sh file

```
%pre -f xyz.sh
```

I tried the above approach but I am not able to get this to work.

So the question

where to place the script, in this example xyz.sh

and how does it become available to the `%pre` section since the `%pre` is called even before any files that are a part of the rpm is copied to the target machine.

Comment: Can't you just put your script directly in the %pre? Why do you need it as seperated sh file?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably just put the contents directly in the proper spec file section, but you can also:

Install it onto the system, then call it in the post-install script, or

Reference it from within the spec file, like:

```
Source1: xyz.sh

...

%{SOURCE01}

or

%{_sourcedir}/xyz.sh
```