# How to use the scripts already inside the RPM file as pre-install or post-install scripts

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am building an RPM package that packages the various files that includes properties files, config files, scripts, JARs etc. 
Now when writing the %pre, %post, %preun and %postun scritptlets, I need to make use of some of the scripts that I have in say scripts/ folder (which has been packaged in RPM).
So, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
%pre
export scripts/important.sh
someFunctionFromImportant parameter
%post
. scripts/anotherScript.sh
someFuncFromAnotherScript parameters
```

Now, since I want to be able to just copy paste this RPM on any system and just install it and the `%pre` and `%post` scriptlests must run. 
I have already gone through so many tutorials and still searching for a way to accomplish this. 
Note: My requirements do not allow me to have those scripts already present on that system where the RPM is being installed. It is like from the RPM file itself, everything should happen cleanly, the install along with the pre and post install scripts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rpmbuild: using script files contained in the package in %pre script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813436/rpmbuild-using-script-files-contained-in-the-package-in-pre-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `%post`, however `%pre` is run just *before* a package is installed, which would mean your scripts are not yet available.

You could package your scripts in a separate RPM, making that a dependency of the RPM from which you want to run the scripts in the `%pre` section.  That would of course have the drawback that uninstalling the caller-RPM would not remove the scripts-RPM.  But it works.

Further reading:

- [Install/Erase-time Scripts](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html#S2-RPM-INSIDE-ERASE-TIME-SCRIPTS)